# Copy filtered records to a new temporary sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy some filtered records to a new sheet in the same excel. But, its just copying the header and not the records. Please suggest. I have defined nc_it_an_sub as the count of records displayed after putting auto filter.

```
Workbooks("WB1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:N" & nc_it_an_sub).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("WB1.xlsx").Worksheets("Temp Sheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: How do you do it? Please show your code, we cannot help you if we don't see what you did. You might take a [tour] and read [ask] to improve your question. Also note that VBA and VBScript is not the same, please correct your tags which one you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
nc_it_an_sub = 10
Workbooks("WB1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:N" & nc_it_an_sub).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("WB1.xlsx").Worksheets("Temp Sheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial _
                                                         Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

If it works, then in your case `nc_it_an_sub` is getting value of `1` and this should be fixed.

---

In general, you do not need to use `Select` in order to `Copy` a range:

```
Workbooks("WB1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:N" & nc_it_an_sub).Copy
Workbooks("WB1.xlsx").Worksheets("Temp Sheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial _
                                                         Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

or even as a 1-liner:

```
Worksheets("Source").Columns("A:D").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Target").Range("a1")
```

Comment: At times, value of nc_it_an_sub is 1, and I want that 2nd row to be fetched. which is not happening. And I didn't understood the difference between the code whih I have written and you have mentioned. Please tell me the difference.

Comment: @user9351236 - the code is avoiding `Select` and is making sure that `nc_it_an_sub` is more than 2

Comment: Please let me know if the value of nc_it_an_sub  is 1, then how can I proceed, because it will vary everytime I extract the file. It might be 0 as well.

Comment: @user9351236 - if it varies your code should be ok. The question is how do you assign value to `nc_it_an_sub`

Answer (score 0):

You could copy just the visible cells.

As an example add this code to a Worksheet module.
This piece of code isn't essential - it creates a filter when you double-click a cell.
It filters the current region down to the value you double-clicked.

```
Private rCellClicked As Range

'Code to create a filtered range.  
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    With ActiveSheet
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
            rCellClicked.Select
        Else
            With Target
                .CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=.Column - .CurrentRegion.Column + 1, Criteria1:=.Value
            End With
            Set rCellClicked = Target

            'This procedure will copy the cells to a new sheet.
            CopyFiltered Target.CurrentRegion

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

This procedure copies the visible cells in your filtered list (including headings) to a range A1 in a new sheet:

```
Public Sub CopyFiltered(FilteredRange As Range)

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    FilteredRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wrkSht.Range("A1")

End Sub
```